# How to upgrade R version on WSL?

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux, and `apt-get update` isn't finding the newest versions of `r-base`.  On Ubuntu 16.04, the newest R version it gets is 3.2.3.  How do I upgrade to newer versions of R?

Comment: 2.3.2? I would believe 3.2.x but 2.3.x can't be right

Comment: @Dason you're right- my mistake.  I wrote 2.3.2 instead of 3.2.3.  Just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the version of `r-base` in the default Ubuntu repository is behind the newest version of `r-base` from CRAN.

**The solution is to add R-CRAN to `/etc/apt/sources.list`**, using the instructions here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade r-base  # This upgrades r-base if it's already installed; otherwise it doesn't install it
```

Comment: That is precisely how you are supposed to upgrade from an add-on repo, and what is written in the README.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel the issue is that r-base comes with the default ubuntu repo, but that version is stuck at 3.2.3.  You don't need to install the CRAN add-on repo to install r-base, but you do need to install the CRAN add-on repo to get an r-base version higher than 3.2.3.

Comment: I am aware. I have maintained the Debian package that the Ubuntu package is based on for close to twenty years, and have been using these on Ubuntu for close to a decade too.  But what you describe really is just what it is in the README so this is not all that novel as a question...

Comment: Speaking of stuck, can you upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04?  That would give you R 3.4.4 in the distro and lots of other newer things ... and still allow you to get the newest R via CRAN.

Comment: Thank you @DirkEddelbuettel for maintaining the package, and for helping me better understand the context around my question.

Comment: You're welcome.  And as always there is a lot of "stuff" and context.  The r-sig-debian list (off the R list server) is a good (and friendly) place too for Debian and Ubuntu questions.

Answer (score 1):

As @DirkEddelbuettel said in his comments, this [README](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) has helpful information for how you can update your R version in a Windows subsystem for Linux (WSL) setting. For me, I updated from R 3.4 to R 4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I am running bionic (I used `lsb_release -a` to find out), and I wanted R 4.0 so I picked the appropriate deb line (for me: `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/`) to add to my /etc/apt/sources.list file (had to use `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` to add this line to the end). Then I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install r-base`. Now I have 4.0.2, the newest version. Just pick the particular Ubuntu/R combo that you want based on the options from the README. I hope this can help someone.